# Difference between 2 DTD tag

Tags: xml, dtd, dtd-parsing

I want to know what is difference between this 2 ELEMENT tag :

```
<!ELEMENT bank (account*, customer*, depositor*)>
```

and

```
<!ELEMENT bank (account | customer | depositor )*>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, the first ELEMENT declaration is saying the child elements have to be in a specific order. The second ELEMENT declaration is saying the child elements can be in any order.

The following means: a `bank` element containing zero or more `account` elements, followed by zero or more `customer` elements, followed by zero or more `depositor` elements. (In that specific order.)

```
<!ELEMENT bank (account*, customer*, depositor*)>
```

The following means: a `bank` element containing zero or more `account` or `customer` or `depositor` elements (in any order).

```
<!ELEMENT bank (account | customer | depositor )*>
```

The '`,`' means "followed by" and the '`|`' means "or". The '`*`' means zero or more. Also, a '`+`' means one or more (at least one).

Answer (score -1):

It denotes a regular expression. Though I'm not very good at that, I think the second  tag accepts sub-element of either account or customer or depositor.

Comment: It does not denote a regular expression.